# e.stopPropagation() is not a function in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a table where there are two things :

Click event on the row level

and click while checking a check box inside that row.

And when , **checkbox is checked I do not want the Click event on tr to be fired.**

```
   <tbody data-bind="foreach:CustomerList">
        <tr onclick="removepage();" onmouseover="changeRowColor(this)" onmouseout="restoreRowColor(this)">

            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" data-bind="click:$parent.customerClick(event)" type="checkbox">

            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                <span class="name" data-bind="text:customerName" />

            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:siteName" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Now in customerClick() ; I tried to achieve the same.

```
   customerClick: function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
```

But it did not work.

It says , `e.stopPropagation();` is not a function also.

Please tell me how to do that .

Comment: When `stopPropagation` is a jQuery function, and you bind the events with knockout, what do you expect?!

Comment: @eisbehr Oh My Bad. Then how to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: According to KnockoutJS documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) event abject is passed as a second parameter fo the click-handling function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout comes with a binding for such an occasion - [`clickBubble`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-4-preventing-the-event-from-bubbling):

```
<input class="checkbox" data-bind="click:$parent.customerClick(event), clickBubble: false" type="checkbox">
```

Setting it to `false` on your `input` will prevent the click event from reaching the handlers further up the tree.

Comment: Lovely . But still the checkbox needs to be checked just . That's not happening.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue.  Perhaps you should investigate the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html), rather than trying to handle the click yourself.